# TDMS_INDEX or TDMS to CSV

Tags: matlab, csv, plot

I want to convert either a **TDMS file** or a **TDMS_INDEX file** to a **CSV-file**.
For this specific task, I would need some kind of converter. What would you suggest me to do?

I need to read data from a TDMS file, as I want to plot it. My company would be okay, if I could convert the TDMS file to a CSV, *so we can plot the CSV file on R-Studio (for instance).*

We did some tests on batteries. So there is a massive table with a lot of data regarding voltage, current, force etc.

Any suggestion, program, app would be nice.
Thank you!

Comment: I have good experience with this snippet... although eventually I've written my on wrapper around it to create timeseries-objects  (which you don't need) https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30023-tdms-reader

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try my luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Only 3 years late to the party, but an answer just the same.

The easiest approach is to use the TDM Excel Plug-In from National Instruments. As of April 2023, you can find a link to that here:

https://www.ni.com/en-gb/support/downloads/tools-network/download.tdm-excel-add-in-for-microsoft-excel.html#378046

I would recommend downloading the NI Package Manager (also on the same page) to facilitate the download and installation. Once installed, you open the TDMS file into Excel. From there it is simply a case of exporting to CSV.